# Syntax error in mysql common table expression

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

this simple query throws a syntax error:

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM expense_type) SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM expense_type) SELECT * FROM cte1' at line 1

While `SELECT * FROM expense_type` works properly.

I think CTE should be supported, when I type `mysql -V` I get this output:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: 'I think CTE should be supported,' - not until version 8 (there is no version 14.4 btw)

Comment: That seems to be the version of your mysql command-line client, which doesn't need to match the server version. To get server version you can run this query: `select version();`. As said, CTE is not supported in MySQL/5 or earlier.

Comment: That's it, my server version is 5.7.24